# CSS Dropdown menu problem

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I downloaded a free CSS template to use it in my ASP.NET project, but I tried many times to convert simple menu to dropdown menu's, Help please, I'm not familiar with CSS.

I uploaded the style here : http://www.apps-srv.com/electronix

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not seeing any attempt at a dropdown. Where (which menu) are you trying to make a dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you've provided is no longer valid, but the comment from toddsler says that there's no evidence at an attempt at a dropdown, so I'm going to go off that.

I suggest checking out [this article from A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns), as well as [this one](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/horizdropdowns/). The first does vertical dropdowns from a horizontal menu, while the second does a vertical menu with dropdowns that go out to the right, then down. They should help you get started.